# Filtering Microsoft.Data.Analysis.DataFrame columns for matching substrings

Tags: c#, .net, dataframe

[The simple program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BDWwUd)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.Analysis;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] names = { "Carl", "Charlotte", "Carla", "Carlos", "Owen" };
        int[] ages = { 23, 19, 42, 64, 35 };
        double[] heights = { 1.91, 1.62, 1.72, 1.57, 1.85 };

        DataFrameColumn[] columns = {
            new StringDataFrameColumn("Name", names),
            new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<int>("Age", ages),
            new PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<double>("Height", heights),
        };

        DataFrame df = new(columns);
        Console.WriteLine("Original df:");
        Console.WriteLine(df);
        PrimitiveDataFrameColumn<bool> paramFilter = df.Columns["Name"].ElementwiseEquals("Carl");
        var dfFiltered = df.Filter(paramFilter);
        Console.WriteLine("Filtered df:");
        Console.WriteLine(dfFiltered);
    }
}
```

filters a Microsoft.Data.Analysis.DataFrame column for a specific string and correctly outputs

```
Original df:
Name  Age   Height
Carl  23    1.91  
Charlotte19    1.62  
Carla 42    1.72  
Carlos64    1.57  
Owen  35    1.85  

Filtered df:
Name  Age   Height
Carl  23    1.91
```

How can this code be changed, such that it filters based on a substring like "Carl" and outputs

```
Original df:
Name  Age   Height
Carl  23    1.91  
Charlotte19    1.62  
Carla 42    1.72  
Carlos64    1.57  
Owen  35    1.85  

Filtered df:
Name  Age   Height
Carl  23    1.9
Carla 42    1.72  
Carlos64    1.57
```

?